# PDO multiple parameter binding for prepared statement

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have a prepared statement in PDO with multiple parameters, is there a way to bind the parameters in group, or chain the calls so as to avoid tediously calling `bindParam` for every item ?

What it looks like right now (I have even more parametrized queries elsewhere):

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO users (name, pass, mail, created, timezone_name, hash_pass, salt) VALUES (:name, :pass, :mail, :created, :timezone, :hashed, :salt") ;

$stmt->bindParam(':name', $name, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindParam(':pass', $pass, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindParam(':mail', $mail, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindParam(':created', $date, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt->bindParam(':timezone', $timezone, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindParam(':hashed', $hash, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindParam(':salt', $salt, PDO::PARAM_STR);

$stmt->execute();
```

Comment: @SergeyBelyakov the parameters are not all the same type

Comment: [It's not a problem](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo#prepared)

Comment: @blackbird57 hmm. Could you build any multidimensional array wich will contain parameter, key and value per each item which needs to be binded

Comment: @blackbird57 like 
`[$name, ':name', 'PDO::PARAM_STR']`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do it at execute time?

```
$stmt->execute(array(':name' => $name, etc....))
```

Using the formal `bindParam()` really only makes sense if you're going to be executing the statement in a loop and will be changing the values in `$name` and the other variables in the loop. If it's a fire/forget single-execution query, might as well just pass the values in the `execute()` call and skip the formal binding - it's a lot of extra work for basically no benefit.

Comment: Will this implicitly bind them though ? What I'm trying to do is have PDO properly escape them to protect against injections

Comment: there's no binding at all, except for the duration of the `execute()` call. The end-result is the same as if you had bound those values. you still get the injection defense and whatnot, just no permanent link between a placeholder and a php var.

Answer (score 1):

Yes there is an alternative:

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO users (name, pass, mail, created, timezone_name, hash_pass, salt) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)") ;
$values = [$name, $pass, $mail, $date, $timezone, $hash, $salt];
$stmt->execute($values);
```

You have positional parameters the one I'm showing you and you have named parameters, Marc B's example.

Choose which one suits you.

**Side note:** you can never mix positional and named parameters.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO users (name, pass, mail, created, timezone_name, hash_pass, salt) VALUES (:name, :pass, :mail, :created, :timezone, :hashed, :salt");

$stmt->execute([
    ':name' => $name,
    ':pass' => $pass,
    ':mail' => $mail,
    ':created' => $created,
    ':timezone' => $timezone,
    ':hashed' => $hashed,
    ':salt' => $salt
]);
```

Comment: You should read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11321491/when-to-use-single-quotes-double-quotes-and-backticks and your elements needs to be separated with commas - not my downvote though.

Comment: How does this bind the parameters ?

Comment: @blackbird57 I fixed the quotes and commas now.

Comment: @Qirel Thanks, It is fixed now.